# How do you implement UIWebViewDelegate from a Cordova iOS plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I have an existing Cordova app where I have manually modified `MainViewController.m` to add my own `UIWebViewDelegate` implementation -- however, I'd like to do this the "right" way and use a plugin (so I can truly treat the platform code as a build artifact).

From [this guide](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Setting%20Delegates%2C%20Preferences%20and%20Script%20Message%20Handlers%20in%20the%20WebView.md), I see that I should be able to set my `UIWebViewDelegate` from my plugin code; however, this isn't working. My implementation is not getting called.

In [the code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/3507af4ac68ed13cfb4d8ecfd0e91e747a9c6875/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewEngine.m#L179), it appears to be always using the `CDVViewController` as the delegate, no matter what is passed in.

Is this a bug? Am I just doing it wrong? What's the correct way to do this?

My scenario here is to trap the `didFailLoadWithError` event for some special handling (our Cordova app uses remote resources, and I want to allow a retry option if they don't load). This is working just fine when I modify the application source directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consultation with the Cordova folks, it seems that this is a bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14076

A patch has been submitted and accepted for a future release of `cordova-ios`.

For anyone else who is looking to do this in the future, my suggestion is for your `UIWebViewDelegate` implementation to store a pointer to the previous delegate set on `UIWebView`, and forward all methods to that delegate. This is required for Cordova to work correctly, if you are not copying/pasting the functionality of the existing delegate into your own.